# Google Play Service

Tags: android

В `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps'` входит ли `google place api`?

Если нет, то как прописать правильно?

Просто не охото всю `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services'` вставлять т.к. приложение разбухает ппц как.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не входит, надо добавить

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
```

[Источник](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)

Comment: Ай, спасибо тебе за источник, выручил! Дай бог те здоровья!

Comment: Всегда рад помочь, спасибо!